# How to extend the intent distance in the File Management area of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the following picture shown, the indent distance for each sub line is very short.

[image]

If you compare it to the following picture,

[image]

you will find that the former picture is very difficult to identify whether a folder is a sub-folder or not.

Is there any recommended theme or configuration to extend the intend distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Workbench`>`Tree: Indent` (`"workbench.tree.indent"` in JSON). You can set it to any amount of pixels.